Updating my site led to a broken drush, cannot fix
I have run Drupal sites for a long time, and as many of you, have come up with some scripts to aid me. Today, something came out wrongly... and I cannot fix it!
In short, my updating script goes over my ~15 Drupal 10 sites, and does (am sharing this just to show this was automated, and I don't have a way to know where the breakage happened):

Set maintenance mode to 1:
./vendor/drush/drush/drush sset system.maintenance_mode 1


Update drupal core:
composer update 'drupal/core-*' --with-all-dependencies


Go over all of the modules pending an update and update them:
MOD_TO_UPDATE=$(composer outdated drupal/* 2>/dev/null | grep ^drupal | awk '{print $1}')
for MODULE in $MOD_TO_UPDATE
do  
    echo echo "  ‣ Actualizando módulo $MODULE"
    composer update $MODULE --with-all-dependencies
done


Applies needed DB updates, rebuilds cache, and disables maintenance:
 ./vendor/drush/drush/drush updatedb
 ./vendor/drush/drush/drush cache:rebuild
 ./vendor/drush/drush/drush sset system.maintenance_mode 0



Today... something got botched. And I don't have a full log to understand what went wrong :-\
Now drush dies at every invocation, with:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: is_link(): Argument #1 ($filename) must be of type string, Drush\Config\Environment given in /srv/(...)/vendor/webflo/drupal-finder/src/DrupalFinder.php:153"
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/(...)/vendor/webflo/drupal-finder/src/DrupalFinder.php(153): is_link()
#1 /srv/(...)/vendor/webflo/drupal-finder/src/DrupalFinder.php(75): DrupalFinder\DrupalFinder->discoverRoots()
#2 /srv/(...)/vendor/drush/drush/src/Preflight/Preflight.php(310): DrupalFinder\DrupalFinder->__construct()
#3 /srv/(...)/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(58): Drush\Preflight\Preflight->preflight()
#4 /srv/(...)/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php(40): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun()
#5 /srv/(...)/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(139): Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run()
#6 /srv/(...)/vendor/drush/drush/drush(4): require('...')
#7 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/libros.iiec.unam.mx/vendor/webflo/drupal-finder/src/DrupalFinder.php on line 153

I found a Drush pull request in GitHub, apparently for this problem, but applying it didn't help me. There is also a Drush issue about this, and somebody reports that updating Drush to 12.5.2 helped them, but it didn't solve the issue for me.
I cannot find a way out of here. Please help! 

Did Drush upgrade in step 3? If so, what is the before-and-after version?

Run composer update to update the entire project. Then update.php in the browser before testing drush from the command line again.

In my backup, I have Drush 12.4. It now mentions 12.5.

@4uk4, I did as you suggested (using the $settings['update_free_access'] = TRUE trick to log in without a functioning drush ), but I seem to be stuck at the same spot ☹

Interestingly... I don't really know composer — After the update, composer.json lists "drush/drush": "^12.5", but composer.lock still mentions "drush/drush": "<12.4.3".

This is a conflict for lower drush versions. You have to look at the version below "name": "drush/drush"

#3 is unusual. It could be equivalent to composer update "drupal/*" --with-all-dependencies.

So it is still showing 12.4.3 (in composer.lock).
WHOOP!
I don't know what happened (maybe it is that I manually cleared the caches in the database?), but drush now worked correctly! (in one of the sites... still have many others to check)

composer why-not drush/drush 12.5.2.

Thanks @monalisa. It tells me that There is no installed package depending on "drush/drush" in versions not matching 12.5.2...
And now it allowed me to update. Good! Lets see if it holds for the other sites.

OK! It seems it got all sorted out. Taking from both monalisa and 4uk4's answers, I managed to get out of the unhappy place I was stuck at.
Thanks to you both! (not explicitly @-ing you as Stack Exchange does not like multiple mentions per post... :-\ )

I have faced a similar issue. Once I updated Drush to 12.5.2, it was resolved.

So, all in ll, what worked in the end were the following steps.

I updated the full project using composer update
I entered $SITE/update.php


As I was not logged in (I usually log in using drush uli), I edited each site's settings.php to set $settings['update_free_access'] to TRUE


Unset maintenance mode and clear caches, by logging into the database and issuing the following query.
UPDATE `key_value` SET `value` =   'b:0;' WHERE `name` = 'system.maintenance_mode' ; 
TRUNCATE `cachetags`;
TRUNCATE `cache_bootstrap`;
TRUNCATE `cache_config`;
TRUNCATE `cache_container`;
TRUNCATE `cache_data`;
TRUNCATE `cache_default`;
TRUNCATE `cache_discovery`;
TRUNCATE `cache_dynamic_page_cache`;
TRUNCATE `cache_entity`;
TRUNCATE `cache_menu`;
TRUNCATE `cache_page`;
TRUNCATE `cache_render`;
TRUNCATE `cache_toolbar`;


I ran again drush.


It worked! \o/
